# Supply voltage of stepper motors

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, stepper-motor

I'm going to use the following stepper motor drive chip:
http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00255075.pdf

And I have choosen the following AC/DC converter:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1766195.pdf

The output voltage of the AC/DC converter is 12V, the motor supply voltage should be 8-45 V.

Is it necessarily to use a voltage regulator to stabilize the supply voltage? (For example switch-mode power supply.)
Or can the output of the AC/DC converter directly used to supply the motors with the drive IC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally fine to use an unregulated supply for powering motors, as long as the supply voltage falls comfortably within the motor driver/controller's operating range. Make sure it can handle the current draw of the motor as well.

For providing VDD (the logic supply voltage) to the chip, you'll probably want to provide a regulated 3.3 V or 5 V.

Comment: Yes, the VDD will be regulated to 3.3 V.